# Rotate minor ticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting the following chart :

[image]

with the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 3))
mpf.candlestick_ohlc(ax,quotes, width=0.01)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mpl.dates.HourLocator(interval=4) )
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')) 
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I would like to also rotate the minor ticks: How would i do that?

Subsidiary question is there a way to rotate both major and minor tick with a single command?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may rotate by code of one line `plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_minorticklabels(), rotation=90)`.

Answer (score 5):

While dealing with the problem myself, I discovered that you can also easily accomplish this with a single statement using the [`tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html):

```python
ax.tick_params(axis="x", which="both", rotation=45)
```

This will rotate labels on your **x** `axis`, and the `which` option allows you to choose between minor, major or both. In case you have multiple plots you will have to do this for every plot in the figure.

Answer (score 2):

By exploring a little, I discovered that `ax.get_xminorticklabels()` is a list with a `text` class element.

```
>>> print(type(ax.get_xminorticklabels()[0])) 
<class 'matplotlib.text.Text'>
```

And `text` can be [rotated](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_rotation)!

```
>>> for text in ax.get_xminorticklabels():
>>>     text.set_rotation(90)
```

[image: xminorticklabels_rotate_example]

You only have to be careful that they do not overlap.