# Rotating minor tick labels for categorical Bokeh plot

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to rotate the major- *and the minor axis* within a multi-categorical plot in Bokeh (similar to what is done for major tick labels [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354648/how-to-rotate-x-axis-labels-in-bokeh-figure) and done within matplotlib [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390487/matplotlib-rotate-minor-tick). When having several categories, their labels/text often get smeared together.

Taking some inspiration from the [Bokeh documentation on Categorical Data](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#nested-categories) the result, using Bokehs `vbar` functionality, would look something like

[image: Plot with rotated minor *and* major x-axis]

The major axis can be set using

```
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
```

Yet I can't find any way of actually doing the same for the minors...

```
? p.xaxis.minor[0]_label_orientation = pi/4 ?
? p.xaxis.minor[1]_label_orientation = pi/3 ?
...
```

Any thoughts out there would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Every seaborn plot is a matplotlib plot, hence [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184484/how-to-add-group-labels-for-bar-charts-in-matplotlib) together with the linked matplotlib tick rotation would directly be applicable to seaborn. In any case, you need to decide if you want a matplotlib or a bokeh solution. In case you want both, ask two separate questions.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Changed to Bokeh. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This capability was added in Bokeh `0.12.16`, you can now do:

```
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = "vertical"
p.xaxis.subgroup_label_orientation = "normal"
p.xaxis.group_label_orientation = 0.8
```

---

<strike>It's not possible in Bokeh 0.12.13, the orientation of labels for levels other than the first one is always `parallel`: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.13/bokehjs/src/coffee/models/axes/categorical_axis.coffee#L89-L92</strike>

You're welcome to create a GitHub issue with a feature request if you need this functionality.